# scala's for yield comprehension used with Future. How to wait until future has returned?

Tags: scala

I have a function which provides a Context:

```
def buildContext(s:String)(request:RequestHeader):Future[Granite.Context] = {
    .... // returns a Future[Granite.Context]
}
```

I then have another function which uses a Context to return an Option[Library.Document]:

```
def getDocument(tag: String):Option[Library.Document] = {
   val fakeRequest = play.api.test.FakeRequest().withHeaders(CONTENT_TYPE -> "application/json")

   val context = buildContext(tag)(fakeRequest)

   val maybeDoc = context.getDocument //getDocument is defined on Granite.Context to return an Option[Library.Document]

}
```

How would this code take into account if the Future has returned or not? I have seen for/yield used to wait for the return but I always assumed that a for/yield just flatmaps things together and has nothing really to do with waiting for Futures to return. I'm kinda stuck here and don't really no the correct question to ask!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The other two answers are misleading. A `for yield` in Scala is a compiler primitive that gets transformed into `map` or `flatMap` chains. Do not use `Await` if you can avoid it, it's not a simple issue.

You are introducing blocking behaviour and you have yet to realise the systemic damage you are doing when blocking.

When it comes to `Future`, `map` and `flatMap` do different things:

**map**
is executed when the future completes. It's an asynchronous way to do a type safe mapping.

```
val f: Future[A] = someFutureProducer
def convertAToB(a: A): B = {..}
f map { a => convertAToB(a) }
```

**flatMap**

is what you use to chain things:

```
someFuture flatMap {
  _ => {
    someOtherFuture
  }
}
```

The equivalent of the above is:

```
for {
  result1 <- someFuture
  result2 <- someOtherFuture
} yield result2
```

In Play you would use `Async` to handle the above:

```
Async {
    someFuture.map(i => Ok("Got result: " + i))
}
```

**Update**

I misunderstood your usage of Play. Still, it doesn't change anything. You can still make your logic asynchronous.

```
someFuture onComplete {
  case Success(result) => // doSomething
  case Failure(err) => // log the error etc
}
```

The main difference when thinking asynchronously is that you always have to `map` and `flatMap` and do everything else inside `Future`s to get things done. The performance gain is massive.

The bigger your app, the bigger the gain.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but since he's not using Play, the Await is unavoidable. In Play, the Async I believe is just freeing the app to process other requests until everything works out for the  current one, however, the client would be still Awaiting his response.

Comment: @Peter Not necessarily. To understand the difference between an Async await and a blocking await, read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21558858/scala-futures-what-is-the-main-thread-expected-to-do-while-futures-are-executin/21559897#21559897

Comment: I'm confused, so he should never Await to get the wanted result? how would he proceed? And I'm only talking about Scala, no Play involved.

Comment: @Peter Basically, all your logic becomes async chains. It's the same thing really, if you know about daemon threads and app lifecycles.

A web server has nothing to do with it.

Comment: Yes that I understood, but here is what bothers me, imagine that we have a simple program, that would call a method that returns a Future of string, this method, does a lot of things, so the String is not instantly available when the method is called, and imagine that our program has to only print that String, if this program doesn't await for the result of that Future, how is it going to print that String? I'm really confused now BTW. :)

Comment: Ah, through callbacks, onComplete, onSucess... But aren't those Awaiting under the hood?

Comment: @Peter There are 2 main ways to wait for a result. Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21558858/scala-futures-what-is-the-main-thread-expected-to-do-while-futures-are-executin/21559897#21559897

Answer (score 6):

When using a for-comprehension on a `Future`, you're not waiting for it to finish, you're just saying: when it is finished, use it like this, and For-comprehension returns another `Future` in this case.

If you want to wait for a future to finish, you should use the `Await` as follows:

```
val resultContext = Await.result(context , timeout.duration)
```

Then run the getDocument method on it as such:

```
val maybeDoc = resultContext.getDocument
```

**EDIT**

The usual way to work with Futures however is to wait until the last moment before you `Await`. As pointed out by another answer here, Play Framework does the same thing by allowing you to return `Future[Result]`. So, a good way to do things would be to only use for-comprehensions and make your methods return Futures, etc, until the last moment when you want to finally return your result.

Comment: Why are you casting?  `Await` is typed.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `scala.concurrent.Await` for that:

```
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import scala.concurrent.Await

def getDocument(tag: String):Option[Library.Document] = {
   val fakeRequest = play.api.test.FakeRequest().withHeaders(CONTENT_TYPE -> "application/json")
   val context = Await.result(buildContext(tag)(fakeRequest), 42.seconds)
   val maybeDoc = context.getDocument

}
```

But `Await` will block thread while future is not completed, so would be better either make `buildContext` a synchronous operation returning `Granite.Context`, or make `getDocument` async too, returning `Future[Option[Library.Document]]`.

Answer (score 1):

Once you are in a future you must stay in the future or you must wait until the future arrives.

Waiting is usually a bad idea because it blocks your execution, so you should work in the future.

Basically you should change your `getDocument` method to return a `Future` to something like `getDocument(tag: String):Future[Option[Library.Document]]`

Then using `map` ro `flatMap`, you chain your future calls:

`return buildContext(tag)(fakeRequest).map(_.getDocument)`

If `buildContext` fails, map will wrap the `Failure`

Then call

```
getDocument("blah").onComplete {
    case Success(optionalDoc) => ...
    case Failure(e) =>...
}
```